# problemas al implementar un upload con net6 y ajax

Tags: ajax, .net-6.0

estuve investigando bastante de como subir una imagen y almacenarla en una carpeta en un servidor en la nube donde tengo alojado un proyecto web. Debo realizarlo con net6 y ajax

este es mi codigo en el .net

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.IO;
namespace API_Mangoo.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FilesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("copy")]
        public IActionResult CopyFile([FromForm] IFormFile file, string destinationFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
                {
                    return BadRequest("No se proporcionó ningún archivo.");
                }

                using (var stream = new FileStream(destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }

                return Ok("El archivo se ha copiado correctamente.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest($"Hubo un error al copiar el archivo: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

este es mi script

```
function moverarchivos(){
    var file = $("#fileCompanyFrm")[0].files[0];
    var destinationFilePath  = 'http://localhost:8080/Mangoo/Img/Platos/';
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("destinationFilePath", destinationFilePath);
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:7265/api/Files/copy",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
            alert("El archivo se ha copiado correctamente.");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Hubo un error al copiar el archivo: " + error);
        }
    });
};
```

me sale el alert del error y en el error encuentro esto

```
{type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",…}
errors
: 
{destinationFilePath: ["The destinationFilePath field is required."]}
status
: 
400
title
: 
"One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId
: 
"00-44ed19b7de5f9b9e956ea9e78866a739-00c67924288ed274-00"
type
: 
"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
```

he cambiado varias veces la variable y siempre me sale este mismo error, ya no se que mas hacer

estuve usando una variable

var destinationFilePath  = '/Img/Platos/';
var destinationFilePath  = 'A:/Descargas';

con cualquier cosa que use, sale error

gracias por su ayuda